# Image slider with widget input yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, gallery

I would like to know if you know some simple image slider(I dont meant carousel) where I can use widget path. I used widget from https://github.com/sadovojav/yii2-gallery-module and there is possibility to display images but only as they are. In gallery are two images without thumbnails.

```
use sadovojav\gallery\widgets\Gallery;

?>
<?= Gallery::widget([
    'galleryId' => 2
]); ?>
```

**In Controller:**

```
public function actionGallery()
{


    return $this->render('gallery', [

    ]);
}
```

Do you know some pretty easy way to solve that?

Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question. What is wrong with  https://github.com/sadovojav/yii2-gallery-module  and what do you need?

Comment: i am still trying to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but I dont know how work with the images after display them. Now I see only images. What is expected. I would like to have  view of gallery like -> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-photo-gallery/